# VB.Net trial application

Tags: vb.net, count, demo

how can i make my application goes to function after certain usage
like if i click an button 10 times, then button is disabled
just like trial program,
so far, i can do that on run-time only,
how can i make it count clicks without using Registry?
my program is very simple: convert strings to Base64

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(TextBox1.Text))
End Sub
```

Comment: That's called a **trial**.

Comment: You need to store that somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need `Settings`. [Easily Save and Retrieve Application and User Settings in VB.NET or C# Apps](http://www.dondraper.com/2011/01/easily-save-and-retrieve-application-and-user-settings-in-vb-net-or-c-apps/). First create `ClickCouter` of type `integer` with value `0` in settings (see the article).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   My.Settings.ClickCouter +=1
   My.Settings.Save() 
   If My.Settings.ClickCouter>=10 then Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

It is necessary to check `ClickCouter` also in `Form_Load`. The value is stored in a file in a user profile so the solution is not too "hacker proof" (but is fool proof :-D ).

Comment: i know how this works, but i need away from inside the app :S

Comment: @user2618553: The data are stored outside an application in %userprofile% folder.